# como crear un variable global y que almacene valores en una peticion ajax

Tags: javascript

Como puedo guardar el valor de mi respuesta **AJAX** en esta variable como lo muestra el código pero no me funciona

```
var resp = "";
var UpdateComponent = function(){
        var rute__ =  "http://localhost/comunity/foro/getPostCurrent/",
            loc = window.location,
            index = loc.pathname.indexOf("ost/"),
            pathName = loc.pathname.substring(index+4, loc.pathname.length );
            var resp = ""; 
            $.ajax({
                url:rute__,
                type:"POST",
                data:{rute:pathName},

                success:function(data){
                    var parse = "";
                    if(data != ""){
                        parse = JSON.parse(data);
                        resp = "como estan";

                    }
                }
            });
        return resp;    


    };
```

Comment: tu pregunta te traera problemas, estas retornando una funcion asincrona , para eso utiliza los callback que te comenteo @PabloLozano en el posible duplicado

Answer (score 0):

Estas definiendo `resp` en dos lugares, fuera de la función y dentro. Pero bueno lo que tienes es un error de no saber como funciona el `scope` de **javascript** , crea la variable fuera `var resp = ""`, luego en el `success` de la petición ajax, asignale el valor que deseas , y luego que se ejecute la función es que `resp` tendrá un valor, ejemplo simplificado:

```
var resp = ""
function Mia(){
 $.ajax({
....
success:function(data){ resp = data.texto    }
 })
}

//resp = ""
//ejecuto la función
Mia()
// aquí resp = el valor de data.texto que se le dio en el success
```